# Is is possible to use %r8d with i686-elf-gcc?

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, elf

I'm developing some "fun" labs for a Computer Architecture course that have students write and run a very minimal OS.  I'm following the Bare Bones setup from http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones and using Richard Hull's precompiled i686 cross compiler (https://github.com/rm-hull/barebones-toolchain).

When I try to write assembly code using `%r8d`, I get this error

```
 Error: bad register name `%r8'
```

The Readme says "There are two platform flavors, 32- and 64-bit depending on your host linux environment", but also lists "i686 (32-bit ELF)" as one of the targets.

Am I correct that the source of the problem is that the ELF target is 32-bit?  If so, is there an easy way to get a cross-compiler with a 64-bit ELF target up and running?

Answer (score 1):

I assume what the README says refers to the "CHOST" of the compiler, while the "CTARGET" is always i686 (which is 32-bit.) There is no `%r8d` (or `%r8`, or any `%r{number}`) register, so no you can't use it (it's an x86-64/IA32-E register.)

You can see [my blogpost on CHOST/CBUILD/CTARGET](https://blog.flameeyes.eu/2009/01/the-canonical-target/) to understand the relationship between the different names of platforms for cross-compiling.